# configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables while build ruby from source

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, gcc

I've checked a number of similar questions on stackoverflow but haven't found an answer yet.

I am trying to build Ruby from source as describe here: https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/installation/#building-from-source

Here what i am getting:

```
ubuntu@saucy1:~/ruby-2.1.1$ ./configure
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/ubuntu/ruby-2.1.1':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

Here's my config.log:

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by configure, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was



 $ ./configure

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = saucy1
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 3.11.0-15-generic
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #25-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 30 17:22:01 UTC 2014

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/games
PATH: /usr/local/games


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2904: checking build system type
configure:2918: result: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
configure:3018: checking host system type
configure:3031: result: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
configure:3051: checking target system type
configure:3064: result: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
configure:3544: checking for gcc
configure:3560: found /usr/bin/gcc
configure:3571: result: gcc
configure:3800: checking for C compiler version
configure:3809: gcc --version >&5
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9) 4.8.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

gcc: error: missing argument to '-march='
configure:3820: $? = 0
configure:3809: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
gcc: error: missing argument to '-march='
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --pre$
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.1 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9)
configure:3820: $? = 0
configure:3809: gcc -V >&5
gcc: error: missing argument to '-march='
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3820: $? = 4
configure:3809: gcc -qversion >&5
gcc: error: missing argument to '-march='
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --pre$
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.1 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9)
configure:3820: $? = 0
configure:3809: gcc -V >&5
gcc: error: missing argument to '-march='
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3820: $? = 4
configure:3809: gcc -qversion >&5
gcc: error: missing argument to '-march='
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3820: $? = 4
configure:3840: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3862: gcc    conftest.c  >&5
gcc: error: missing argument to '-march='
configure:3866: $? = 1
configure:3904: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define CANONICALIZATION_FOR_MATHN 1
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
|
| int
| main ()
| {
|
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3909: error: in `/home/ubuntu/ruby-2.1.1':
configure:3911: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_host=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=gcc
ac_cv_target=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ALLOCA=''
AR=''
ARCHFILE=''
ARCH_FLAG=''
AS=''
ASFLAGS=''
BASERUBY='echo executable host ruby is required.  use --with-baseruby option.; false'
BTESTRUBY=''
BUILTIN_ENCOBJS=''
BUILTIN_TRANSOBJS=''
BUILTIN_TRANSSRCS=''
CAPITARGET=''
CC='gcc'
CCDLFLAGS=''
CC_VERSION=''
CFLAGS=''
CHDIR=''
COMMON_HEADERS=''
COMMON_LIBS=''
COMMON_MACROS=''
COUTFLAG=''
CP=''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
CPPOUTFILE=''
CROSS_COMPILING=''
CXX=''
CXXFLAGS=''
DEFS=''
DLDFLAGS=''
DLDLIBS=''
DLEXT2=''
DLEXT=''
DLLWRAP=''
DLNOBJ=''
DOT=''
DOXYGEN=''
DTRACE=''
DTRACE_EXT=''
DTRACE_GLOMMED_OBJ=''
DTRACE_OBJ=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
ENABLE_SHARED=''
ENCOBJS=''
EXECUTABLE_EXTS=''
EXEEXT=''
EXPORT_PREFIX=''
EXTDLDFLAGS=''
EXTLDFLAGS=''
EXTOBJS=''
EXTOUT=''
EXTSTATIC=''
GCC=''
GNU_LD=''
GREP=''
INSTALLDOC=''
INSTALL_DATA=''
INSTALL_PROGRAM=''
INSTALL_SCRIPT=''
LD=''
LDFLAGS=''
LDSHARED=''
LDSHAREDXX=''
LIBEXT=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBPATHENV=''
LIBPATHFLAG=''
LIBRUBY=''
LIBRUBYARG=''
LIBRUBYARG_SHARED=''
LIBRUBYARG_STATIC=''
LIBRUBY_A=''
LIBRUBY_ALIASES=''
LIBRUBY_A_OBJS=''
LIBRUBY_DLDFLAGS=''
LIBRUBY_LDSHARED=''
LIBRUBY_RELATIVE=''
LIBRUBY_SO=''
LIBS=''
LINK_SO=''
LN_S=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
MAINLIBS=''
MAJOR='2'
MAKEDIRS=''
MAKEFILES=''
MANTYPE=''
MINIOBJS=''
MINIRUBY=''
MINOR='1'
MKDIR_P=''
NACL_SDK_ROOT=''
NACL_SDK_VARIANT=''
NACL_TOOLCHAIN=''
NM=''
NROFF=''
NULLCMD=''
OBJCOPY=''
OBJDUMP=''
OBJEXT=''
OUTFLAG=''
PACKAGE=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_NAME=''
PACKAGE_STRING=''
PACKAGE_TARNAME=''
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION=''
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PKG_CONFIG=''
PLATFORM_DIR=''
POSTLINK=''
PREP=''
PYTHON=''
RANLIB=''
RDOCTARGET=''
RI_BASE_NAME=''
RM=''
RMALL=''
RMDIR=''
RMDIRS=''
RPATHFLAG=''
RUBYW_BASE_NAME='rubyw'
RUBYW_INSTALL_NAME=''
RUBY_BASE_NAME='ruby'
RUBY_EXEC_PREFIX=''
RUBY_INSTALL_NAME=''
RUBY_LIB_VERSION=''
RUBY_LIB_VERSION_STYLE=''
RUBY_PROGRAM_VERSION='2.1.1'
RUBY_RELEASE_DATE='2014-02-24'
RUBY_SEARCH_PATH=''
RUBY_SO_NAME=''
RUBY_VERSION_NAME='${RUBY_BASE_NAME}-${ruby_version}'
RUNRUBY=''
RUNRUBY_COMMAND=''
SET_MAKE=''
SHELL='/bin/bash'
SOLIBS=''
STATIC=''
STRIP=''
SYMBOL_PREFIX=''
TEENY='0'
TEST_RUNNABLE=''
THREAD_MODEL=''
TRY_LINK=''
UNIVERSAL_ARCHNAMES=''
UNIVERSAL_INTS=''
USE_RUBYGEMS=''
WERRORFLAG=''
WINDRES=''
XCFLAGS=''
XLDFLAGS=''
XRUBY=''
XRUBY_LIBDIR=''
XRUBY_RUBYHDRDIR=''
XRUBY_RUBYLIBDIR=''
ac_ct_CC='gcc'
ac_ct_CXX=''
ac_ct_OBJCOPY=''
ac_ct_OBJDUMP=''
arch=''
archincludedir=''
archlibdir=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
build_alias=''
build_cpu='x86_64'
build_os='linux-gnu'
build_vendor='unknown'
cflags=' ${optflags} ${debugflags} ${warnflags}'
codesign=''
configure_args=''
cppflags=''
cxxflags=' ${optflags} ${debugflags} ${warnflags}'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
debugflags=''
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec=''
exec_prefix='NONE'
host='x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
host_alias=''
host_cpu='x86_64'
host_os='linux-gnu'
host_vendor='unknown'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libdirname=''
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
optflags=''
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='NONE'
program_transform_name='s&^&&'
psdir='${docdir}'
ridir=''
ruby_pc=''
ruby_version=''
rubyarchdir=''
rubyarchhdrdir=''
rubyarchprefix=''
rubyhdrdir=''
rubylibdir=''
rubylibprefix=''
rubysitearchprefix=''
rubyw_install_name=''
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
setup=''
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sitearch=''
sitearchdir=''
sitearchhdrdir=''
sitearchincludedir=''
sitearchlibdir=''
sitedir=''
sitehdrdir=''
sitelibdir=''
strict_warnflags=''
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target='x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
target_alias=''
target_cpu='x86_64'
target_os='linux'
target_vendor='unknown'
try_header=''
vendorarchdir=''
vendorarchhdrdir=''
vendordir=''
vendorhdrdir=''
vendorlibdir=''
warnflags=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME ""
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
#define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
#define PACKAGE_STRING ""
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define PACKAGE_URL ""
#define CANONICALIZATION_FOR_MATHN 1

configure: exit 77
```

Comment: Take a look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/347466/configure-error-c-compiler-cannot-create-executables

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cant install gcc correctly on ubuntu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22242884/cant-install-gcc-correctly-on-ubuntu)

Comment: This is caused by the same problem as your http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22242884/cant-install-gcc-correctly-on-ubuntu question